# R: How to loop through models dropping one observation at a time?

Tags: r, loops, regression, coefficients

I have trouble looping through a regression model dropping one observation each time to estimate the effect of influential observations.

I would like to run the model several times, each time dropping the ith observation and extracting the relevant coefficient estimate and store it in a vector. I think this could quite easily be done with a fairly straight forward loop, however, I'm stuck at the specifics.

I want to be left with a vector containing n coefficient estimates from n iterations of the same model. Any help would be beneficial!

Below I provide some dummy data and example code.

````
#Dummy data:

set.seed(489)

patientn <- rep(1:400)

gender <- rbinom(400, 1, 0.5)

productid <- rep(c("Product A","Product B"), times=200)

country <- rep(c("USA","UK","Canada","Mexico"), each=50)

baselarea <- rnorm(400,400,60) #baseline area
baselarea2 <- rnorm(400,400,65) #baseline area2

sfactor  <- c(
  rep(c(0.3,0.9), times = 25),
  rep(c(0.4,0.5), times = 25),
  rep(c(0.2,0.4), times = 25),
  rep(c(0.3,0.7), times = 25)
)

rashdummy2a <- data.frame(patientn,gender,productid,country,baselarea,baselarea2,sfactor)

Data <- rashdummy2a %>% mutate(rashleft = baselarea2*sfactor/baselarea*100) ```


## Example of how this can be done manually: 

# model
m1<-lm(rashleft ~ gender + baselarea + sfactor, data = data)

# extracting relevant coefficient estimates, each time dropping a different "patient" ("patientn")

betas <- c(lm(rashleft ~ gender + baselarea + sfactor, data = rashdummy2b, patientn !=1)$coefficients[2],
           lm(rashleft ~ gender + baselarea + sfactor, data = rashdummy2b, patientn !=2)$coefficients[2],
           lm(rashleft ~ gender + baselarea + sfactor, data = rashdummy2b, patientn !=3)$coefficients[2])

# the betas vector now stores the relevant coefficient estimates (coefficient nr 2, for gender) for three different variations of the model.
````

Comment: Sure you want to use the betas to find the influence of individual observations on the model? Alternative is for example leave one out cross validation (LOOCV) as in the caret package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a for loop. In your question you use an object `rashdummy2b` which is not defined. Now I used  `data` but you can replace that by an object of choice.

```
#create list to bind results to
result <- list()

#loop through patients and extract betas
for(i in unique(data$patientn)){

  #construct linear model
  lm.model <- lm(rashleft ~ gender + baselarea + sfactor, data = subset(data, data$patientn != i))
  
  #create data.frame containing patient left out and coefficient
  result.dt <- data.frame(beta = lm.model$coefficients[[2]],
                          patient_left_out = i)
  
  #bind to list
  result[[i]] <- result.dt
}

#bind to data.frame
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

Result

```
head(result) 
      beta patient_left_out
1 1.381248                1
2 1.345188                2
3 1.427784                3
4 1.361674                4
5 1.420417                5
6 1.454196                6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop a particular row (or column) by using a *negative index*. In your case, you proceed as follows:

```
betas <- numeric(nrow(rashdummy2b))  # memory preallocation
for (i in 1:nrow(rashdummy2b)) {
  betas[i] <- lm(rashleft ~ gender + baselarea + sfactor, data=rashdummy2b[-i,])$coefficients[2]
}
```